# Remove Qt libraries on Mac

Tags: macos, qt4, libraries, uninstallation

I want to remove the installed Qt 4.8 libraries and install Qt 4.6 libraries on my mac.

But when I try to install them I get:

> "Qt libraries cannot be installed on this disk. A newer version of
>   this software already exists on this disk"

I removed the *`/usr/local/Qt4.8.x`* folder from the disk but the message is still here.

How can I remove the old libraries?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You shouldn't manually delete a folder unless there is no other option. You should try running the uninstall script first:

```
sudo python /Developer/Tools/uninstall-qt.py
```

The path to this script will be different if you are running the latest Xcode app bundle and not the default Snow Leopard/Lion Xcode.

Comment: Have you managed to do this proposal in Qt5 and El Capitan? I did it unsuccessfully along with other proposals http://stackoverflow.com/a/26811738/54964 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17992836/54964

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't done much Qt5 development on OS X lately. I would imagine that the paths would need to be changed and that some uninstall script still exists, but I can't test this at the moment.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to search it? I have the system here and I can test to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I installed qt via homebrew. To remove I simply wrote the following in the terminal: `brew uninstall qt@4`

Comment: I have used the above command, it works nicely. In my case, two versions of Qt were installed on my system. 1st one I have removed from Qtuninstaller tool, the other one i have run the brew uninstall qt@6. Thanks for your post.