# Uninstall qt 4 from mac os

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

I just installed wrong qt version on my Mac OS. Qt version is 4.8.5. Qt5 is installed into a separate folder, but version 4 is spread over the system, I cannot just delete one folder.

Is there an easy way to uninstall it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Qt libraries on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103017/remove-qt-libraries-on-mac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, there is python script somewhere in /Developer/qt/tools.../uninstall-qt.py

I'm not sure about the names, but you'll recognise the script.

Also, you'll have to run it with sudo, smth like this:

```
sudo python ./uninstall-qt.py
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see any Developer folder

Comment: It's in your HD root, if you have multiple check each one

Comment: Ah, got it! I was looking at my 'home' directory instead of 'root'. Sorry, I'm a new Mac user.

Comment: Have you managed to apply this answer to Qt5 and El Capitan? I do not find any /Developer/ folder. I have also tried this answer unsuccessfully http://stackoverflow.com/a/26811738/54964

Comment: The python script is under `/Developer/Tools/`. My Qt version: 4.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

With later versions of macOS and Qt, the solution seems to be to run the MaintenanceTool, as described [on the Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Howto_do_a_clean_uninstall_and_reinstall_of_qt_sdk) and in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811738/2075003).

You should find the tool in `~/Library/Qt`.