# How to uninstall Qt Creator on Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator, osx-yosemite

I have tried [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Howto_do_a_clean_uninstall_and_reinstall_of_qt_sdk) but when I do, the terminal ask me for password. I don't know what this password is? I don't have any password on my mac, i don't enter any password when I login and I can't get passed the first step below.

```
sudo QtSDK/SDKMaintenanceTool.app/Contents/MacOS/SDKMaintenanceTool
```

I am uninstalling Qt Creator 2.8.1 on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10 I just want to install the latest 5.3.2 version and get rid of the old one. I could probably choose a new folder but I don't want to do that and it doesn't let me install over the current folder.

Comment: Why don't you just double click `SDKMaintenanceTool.app`? You are wrong when you say that *I don't have any password on my mac*. If you have a Mac you have a password. If it is configured not to prompt it at login that doesn't mean you don't have a password. When you install `Mac OS` you are asked to provide a password. Your problem is that you forgot it and you need to reset it somehow: http://youtu.be/QNZkvrsDspo

Comment: @Iuliu where can I double click on it? I can't find it and it doesn't come up in finder

Comment: `cd` into `QtSDK` and type `pwd`. You will get the path to the `SDKMaintenanceTool.app` where you can double click on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically I was not able to locate the file because it never shows up in finder but here is how to get there.

From 'Go' menu on Finder, select 'Go to Folder'

Type ~/Library

This will take you to file system. I had two folders related to Qt (Qt and Qt 5.1). Both folders had MaintenanceTool file in it which I run and it asks if you want to uninstall and select yes. This will uninstall Qt Creator and all its components.

**Update**

Like aksiksi noted in comment below, it maybe installed in root folder for new versions. To go there type `/` in 'Go to Folder' dialog and look for Qt installation there.

Comment: @Masi I'm on El Capitan. Qt creates a folder in ~/Qt5.6.0; the exact name is likely version dependent. Run the MaintenanceTool inside that folder to uninstall Qt.

Comment: Am on Catalina and there is no Qt folder in ~/Library of any user, in /Library, or in /.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the main Qt directory. If you installed it somewhere else, delete that one instead

```
rm -rf ~/Qt
```

Then here are the directories with "Qt" in the name that I found on my system

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Qt
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/QtProject
rm -rf ~/.config/QtProject
```

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly there is no up to date instructions to uninstall Qt 5 even on Qt Wiki. Though you can do it easily (I just did it with Qt 5.15.1).

Launch `MaintenanceTool.app` from Finder, it should be in `/Users/your_user_name/Qt` by default. Click Next, then check on Uninstall only, that's all.

It removed `~/Qt` folder but shamelessly left other folders untouched and you still needs to do @Boris's commands manually:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Qt
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/QtProject
rm -rf ~/.config/QtProject
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is arising because you are using sudo command. Well you have to assign a password to the computer to use that. I also faced the same problem. It's very simple.Just go to

```
System Prefernces-> Users and Groups -> Change password
```

Hope this helps.